# Get all text in an lxml node

Tags: python, lxml

I am using the following approach to print all the text (not html, but actual text contained) within an element node:

```
''.join(node.xpath('//div[@class="title_wrapper"]')[0].itertext())
```

Is there a cleaner approach to doing this?

Comment: You can also try `node.xpath('//div[@class="title_wrapper"]')[0].text_content()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use XPath's [`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-string) function.

If you have large chunks of whitespace from mixed content, you could use XPath's [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-normalize-space) function.

Example of all three (yours and my two)...

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = """<doc>
    <div class="title_wrapper">Some text. Some <span>more</span> text. 
    <span>Even <span>m<span>o</span>re</span> text!</span>
    </div>
</doc>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)

print(''.join(tree.xpath('//div[@class="title_wrapper"]')[0].itertext()))

print(tree.xpath('string(//div[@class="title_wrapper"])'))

print(tree.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="title_wrapper"])'))
```

**Output**

```
Some text. Some more text. 
    Even more text!

Some text. Some more text. 
    Even more text!

Some text. Some more text. Even more text!
```